# Extending LVM partition on Virtualbox/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, partitioning, gparted

I stupidly created a dynamic disk when I created a VM. The disk has been converted to Fixed and the size upped to 20GB. I booted into a GParted live CD and extended the partition up to the maximum.

[image: GParted screen shot]

Through extensive Googling, I then executed the following commands in a terminal:

```
pvresize /dev/sda5
pvscan
(reports 19.76GiB total/in use)

lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/snoopy-vg/root
(4547 extents matches existing size)

resize2fs /dev/snoopy-vg/root
(open: no such file or directory while opening /dev/snoopy-vg/root)
```

If I try...

```
resize2fs /dev/sda5
(resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda5)
```

As you can see, the last command is obviously wrong. Once I boot into the VM proper, nothing has changed...

```
frank@snoopy:~$ df -H
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/snoopy--vg-root  6.0G  5.3G  359M  94% /
```

Is there some last step that I'm missing? What's the secret sauce?

Comment: Have you done `lvchange -ay /dev/snoopy-vg/root` ?

Answer (score 0):

So... I just found the answer, mere seconds after posting this (ain't that always the way?!)

I booted into the VM, did a `sudo su -` and executed the following...

```
resize2fs /dev/snoopy-vg/root [number of available blocks]
```

I could have specified in various different ways (i.e. G for GB).